# How to implement AS2 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, edi

I have a potential client that will be sending data in EDI to us and we need to setup a AS2 endpoint to recieve/request data.

How would I do this in ruby on rails?

See specification here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4130.txt

I will need to program it to permutation 12 on page 8 of the doc:
Sender sends encrypted and signed data and requests a signed receipt.  Receiver sends back the signed receipt.

Has anyone written a gem for this?

I found this solution in php: http://search.cpan.org/~swong/Net-AS2-0.01/lib/Net/AS2.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiving AS2 is a server thing.
AFAICS the recipe is a client?
There are open source AS2 implementations, and commercial ones.
Open source: eg OpenAS, mendelson AS2